# How to check for the existence of this integral?

Tags: integration

How to check for the existence of this integral?

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx
$$

where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the integrand $x\mapsto f(x) = \frac{\{x\}}{x}$ is non-negative, has only countably many discontinuities, and that on every interval of the form $[n+\frac{1}{2},n+1)$ one has $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2x}$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{(0,\infty)} f &\geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{[n+1/2,n+1)} f \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{[n+1/2,n+1)} \frac{dx}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \log\frac{n+1}{n+\frac12} \\&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \log\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{2n}} = \infty
\end{align}$$
the last part as $\log\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{2n}}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2n}$.